# Create tab in line 2

Tags: tabbing

I want to write line such that there is no indentation of the beginning line for the paragraph, but there is an indentation from second line onwards. For instance.

```
This is what I am saying. This is what I am saying. This is what I am 
             saying. This is what I am saying. This is what I am say-
             ing. This is what I am saying. This is what I am saying.
```

I am facing diffiulty in how to do this Latex. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that (very nearly almost) all questions should include a complete minimal working example (MWE) or minimal non-working example (if the question concerns a compilation error).

A simple search of CTAN with `hanging` provides an out-of-the-box solution in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{hangparas}{1.5em}{1}
  \kant[1-3]
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

[image: hanging]

Answer (score 3):

`\hangindent` and `\hangafter` to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \hangafter=1
  \hangindent=4em
  \noindent
  This is what I am saying. This is what I am saying.
  This is what I am saying. This is what I am saying.
  This is what I am saying. This is what I am saying.
  This is what I am saying.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]